# how to fix dynamic memory allocation problem in c?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to learn c and implementing some basic memory allocations.

When I either malloc, calloc or realloc a pointer to int, every time I end up with the same chunk of memory of 8 bytes even when I'm initializing it with malloc with 20 bytes.

How to solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{    
    int* ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);    
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0]));    
    ptr = (int*) realloc(ptr, 10 * sizeof(int));    
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0]));    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You already know the size, because you just specified it in the second argument of `realloc`. If you're asking how you can reap that size from just the pointer, the answer is *you can't*. `sizeof` is an operator that delivers the size of the argument provided. In this case, that's the size of *a pointer*, which on your platform is 8 bytes. That's how `sizeof` works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: You already know the size when you call malloc, no need to calculate anything.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `ptr` has the type `int *`.

So the expression `sizeof(ptr)` gives the size of an object of the type i`nt *` that is in the used by you system it seems is equal to `8`.

Thus this expression

```
sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0])
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
sizeof( int * ) / sizeof( int )
```

and does not depend on how many elements were dynamically allocated.

If you are allocating dynamically an array you should store somewhere (in a variable) its size. Otherwise having only a pointer you are unable to determine the size of the allocated memory extent if the extent does not have a sentinel value.

There is one possibility when you will declare a pointer to an array like for example

```
int ( *ptr )[5] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

In this case dereferencing the pointer you will get the lvalue of the allocated array and can determine its size like

```
sizeof( *ptr ) / sizeof( **ptr );
```

Pay attention to that you have to use the conversion specifier `zu` with expressions of the type `size_t`. Instead of for example this call

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0]));
```

you have to write

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(ptr) / sizeof(ptr[0]));
        ^^^
```

Comment: thank you for your answer..is there anyway to know the amount of memory does this pointer point to?

Comment: @SayedOmar no, there is no standard way to do so and you don't need it. Some implementations have special functions which allows this, but you should just forget about them.

Comment: @SayedOmar In your example the pointer has the type int *. So it points to a scalar  object of the type int.